# OrderedDict sorting incorrectly

Tags: python, python-datetime, ordereddict

As I understand it, the following should result in an `OrderedDict` object with the items sorted by the key, which is a datetime object.

```
ledger = OrderedDict(
    sorted(ledger.items(), key=lambda x: datetime.strftime(x[0], '%d-%m-%Y'))
)
```

However, in my case, the objects are being sorted out of order:

```
OrderedDict([
    (datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), {'net': -33924, 'entries': [{'text': 'Applied to 102101', 'amount': -16962, 'mode': 'debit'}, {'text': 'Applied to 102104', 'amount': -16962, 'mode': 'debit'}]}),
    (datetime.date(2021, 11, 3), {'net': -96118, 'entries': [{'text': 'Applied to 102104', 'amount': -96118, 'mode': 'debit'}]}), 
    (datetime.date(2021, 9, 24), {'net': 18000.0, 'entries': [{'text': 'Payment Received', 'amount': 18000.0, 'mode': 'credit'}]})
])
```

What are the caveats that I am missing here?

Comment: You're sorting by day of month first

Comment: Ahh gotcha, I need to set up my strftime differently

Comment: This is likely caused by the fact that your sorting key is sorted on `str` objects, not on numeric values.

Comment: datetime objects can be sorted, if you just remove the key to convert it to a string that sorts badly doesn't it just work?

Comment: Why are you formatting the date objects as strings at all?

Comment: Thanks everyone. Removing the key fixed it. I think I added that in when I was trying to format the output, but that's obviously the wrong place to be doing this.

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mre]. It looks like the dict aspect is irrelevant here, and you could reproduce the same problem with a plain list of dates: `sorted(dates, key=lambda x: x.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))`. It also helps to have the expected output to avoid confusion like in ddejohn's answer, and the imports to avoid confusion between `datetime` and `datetime.datetime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort in some way that is *not* chronological, you can access the attributes you want to sort by and use tuple sorting:

```py
sorted(datetimes, key=lambda d: (d.month, d.seconds))  # or some other weird sorting
```

If it's just a chronological sort however, then you don't need to bother with any of this:

```py
In [3]: OrderedDict(sorted(ledger.items()))
Out[3]:
OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2021, 9, 24),
              {'net': 18000.0,
               'entries': [{'text': 'Payment Received',
                 'amount': 18000.0,
                 'mode': 'credit'}]}),
             (datetime.date(2021, 10, 1),
              {'net': -33924,
               'entries': [{'text': 'Applied to 102101',
                 'amount': -16962,
                 'mode': 'debit'},
                {'text': 'Applied to 102104',
                 'amount': -16962,
                 'mode': 'debit'}]}),
             (datetime.date(2021, 11, 3),
              {'net': -96118,
               'entries': [{'text': 'Applied to 102104',
                 'amount': -96118,
                 'mode': 'debit'}]})])
```

Comment: `%d` and `%m` are defined so that something like `%Y-%m-%d` will sort lexicographically the same as it does chronologically. But `datetime` objects are *already* sortable chronologically, so there's no need to deconstruct the argument in the key function.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, however I was under the impression OP perhaps wanted some other sorting method.

Comment: No haha, OP just probably needs to call it a day.

Comment: lol, no problem, I've edited to include a bog-standard chronological sort just to answer the question properly.